Thymeleaf form not saving data to database for nested objects in Spring Boot
I don't understand why the entered data from the html template is not saved in the database.
I have an entity Supplies:
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "supplies")
public class Supplies {

    public Supplies() {
        this.badges = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sup", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Badge> badges;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "header_id", nullable = false)
    private InputHeader header;
}

and entity Badge:
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@Entity(name = "badges")
public class Badge {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String badgeMaterial; //материал изготовления - тут всего два варианта ПЕЧАТНЫЙ ПЛАСТИКОВЫЙ
    private String size; //размер - варианты для списка или вписываем вручную(можно оставлять пустым)
    private String chroma; //цветность - варианты для списка или вписываем вручную(можно оставлять пустым)
    private String density; //плотность - варианты для списка или вписываем вручную(можно оставлять пустым)
    private String lamination; //показател ламинации - варианты для списка или вписываем вручную(можно оставлять пустым)
    private String laminationKind; //тип ламинации - тут всего два варианта МАТОВЫЙ ГЛЯНЦЕВЫЙ

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplies_id", nullable = false)
    private Supplies sup;
}

Look at my HTML template:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Input Supplies</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Input Supplies</h1>
    <form th:action="@{/input/saveSupplies}" th:object="${supplies}" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="headerId" th:value="${headerId}" />
        <input type="hidden" name="suppliesId" th:value="${suppliesId}" />

        <div class="badge-fields">
            <h2>Badge 1</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Badge Material</label>
                <select th:field="*{badges[0].badgeMaterial}" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected> -- Select Material -- </option>
                    <option value="PRINTED">Printed</option>
                    <option value="PLASTIC">Plastic</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Size</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[0].size}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Chroma</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[0].chroma}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Density</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[0].density}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Lamination</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[0].lamination}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Lamination Kind</label>
                <select th:field="*{badges[0].laminationKind}" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected> -- Select Lamination Kind -- </option>
                    <option value="MATTE">Matte</option>
                    <option value="GLOSSY">Glossy</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="badge2Fields" class="badge-fields">
            <h2>Badge 2</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Badge Material</label>
                <select th:field="*{badges[1].badgeMaterial}" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected> -- Select Material -- </option>
                    <option value="PRINTED">Printed</option>
                    <option value="PLASTIC">Plastic</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Size</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[1].size}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Chroma</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[1].chroma}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Density</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[1].density}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Lamination</label>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{badges[1].lamination}" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Lamination Kind</label>
                <select th:field="*{badges[1].laminationKind}" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected> -- Select Lamination Kind -- </option>
                    <option value="MATTE">Matte</option>
                    <option value="GLOSSY">Glossy</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>


in my GetMapping endpoint i create all entities
@GetMapping("/input/supplies")
    public String showInputSupplies(@RequestParam("headerId") Long headerId, Model model) {
        Supplies supplies = new Supplies();
        supplies.setHeader(inputService.getInputHeaderById(headerId));
        inputService.saveInputSupplies(supplies);


        Long suppliesId = supplies.getId();

        System.out.println(supplies);
        System.out.println(headerId);
        System.out.println(suppliesId);
        Badge badge1 = new Badge();
        Badge badge2 = new Badge();
        badge1.setSup(inputService.getSuppliesById(suppliesId));
        badge2.setSup(inputService.getSuppliesById(suppliesId));

        supplies.getBadges().add(badge1);
        supplies.getBadges().add(badge2);

        inputService.saveBadge(badge1);
        inputService.saveBadge(badge2);
        model.addAttribute("suppliesId", suppliesId);
        model.addAttribute("supplies", supplies);
//        model.addAttribute("badge1", new Badge());
//        model.addAttribute("badge2", new Badge());
        model.addAttribute("badge1", badge1);
        model.addAttribute("badge2", badge2);
        model.addAttribute("headerId", headerId);
        return "inputSupplies";
    }

I check in the database and see that I have a Supplies instance created with the generated ID, the HeaderID is correctly linked, two Badge instances are also created, also with the generated IDs and the correct binding to Supplies. Next, I go to my template, fill it with data and save it, after which I am redirected to return from PostMapping.
    @PostMapping("/input/saveSupplies")
    public String saveSupplies(@RequestParam("headerId") Long headerId,
                               @ModelAttribute Supplies supplies,
                               @ModelAttribute("badge1") Badge badge1,
                               @ModelAttribute("badge2") Badge badge2,
                               @RequestParam("suppliesId") Long suppliesId,
                               Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Supplies and Badges saved successfully");
        return "redirect:/staff?headerId=" + headerId;
    }

but in the database, all filled fields remain null. What am I doing wrong?

Well you don't seem to do any saving in saveSupplies? At least I don't see anything relating to the DB there. Only in showInputSupplies maybe.
